# what is the use of defining macros same as the identifier

Tags: c++, c, macros

While looking at the poco library i saw some macros which has same identifier as well as the replacemente text:

for example in the file XML/inlucde/XML/expat.h

```
  47   XML_STATUS_ERROR = 0,
  48 #define XML_STATUS_ERROR XML_STATUS_ERROR
  49   XML_STATUS_OK = 1,
  50 #define XML_STATUS_OK XML_STATUS_OK
  51   XML_STATUS_SUSPENDED = 2
  52 #define XML_STATUS_SUSPENDED XML_STATUS_SUSPENDED
```

I was wondering what could be the use of defining macros like that.

Comment: Going to take a wild guess, but this way you can `#ifdef` them ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two use cases here:

- to make everything work if the identifier was `#define`d somewhere else before. You don't want to use value it was defined to, right? So here, you ensure that code using that identifiers will be valid.
- to allow `#ifdef`ing the identifiers (i.e. check if they were already defined).

Answer (score 1):

That does seem quite nonsensical, doesn't it? The only thought I have is that it allows you to use `#ifdef` on the symbol, but I can't see that being useful in this specific example.